# CLANG: Elaborated type refers to a typedef error

Tags: clang

Here is my code snippet

```
template <class T>
struct ClassFriendMaker
{
    typedef T Type;
};

template <class T>

class Singleton
{
    friend class ClassFriendMaker<T>::Type; // Problem in this line
    //Other declaration 
}
```

When compiled with CLANG, it gave me an error:

```
error: elaborated type refers to a typedef
   friend class ClassFriendMaker<T>::Type;
                                      ^
```

May I know what's wrong ? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **class** with **typename** in friend declaration

```
friend class ClassFriendMaker<T>::Type;

friend typename ClassFriendMaker<T>::Type;
```